# Linear Transformation $T-T^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear transformation from a vector space V over reals into V such that
$T-T^2=I$. Show that T is invertible

Solution: I started by multiplying T on both sides and getting

$-T^3=I$

Comment: @André: I think that the OP did calculate correctly. Multiplying by $T$ gives $T^2-T^3=T$. Solving $T^2=T-I$ from the given equation, and plugging that back in the l.h.s. does lead to $-T^3=I$. Of course, your suggestion leads to a simpler solution, but the OP's idea gives $T^{-1}=-T^2$ which also works.

Comment: You are right, OP skipped a step and I was too dim to interpolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T-T^{2}=I$, so $(I-T)T=I\implies ST=I$ with $S=(I-T)$ which means $T$ is left invertible.

*Similarly*, $T-T^{2}=I$, so $T(I-T)=I\implies TU=I$ with $U=(I-T)$ which means $T$ is right invertible, and hence invertible where $T^{-1}=I-T.$

Comment: But what is the relevance of - 'T being a transformation from a vector space to itself'??